# Intuition behind 2NF in normalization of relational databases

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization

2NF does not allow a partial dependency; i.e. any non-prime attribute should not be dependent on a subset of the primary key (excluding itself; otherwise it will be full functional dependency).

But why?

What is the problem we have with partial dependencies?

What protocol will it break if we keep it as it is?

Comment: 2NF "is not allowed to have a partial FD" *on a CK* (candidate key). Also partial FDs are not defined in terms of CKs or prime attributes. Also the definition of partial FD means that 2NF says non-prime attributes are not dependent on a *proper*/*smaller* subset of a CK. Also your "excluding..." is unclear, although you seem to be trying to address the proper/smaller aspect. (Eg you use "itself"/"it" to mean two different things, *and neither are mentioned in the preceding sentence*. Find some academic textbook/slide/course definitions (*many* are online), memorize them, and stick to them.

Comment: 2NF is not of pratical interest and of very scarce theorical interest. Only 3NF and BCNF are significant normal forms, so don't waste your time by pondering about 2NF. On many database books it is simply labeled as “of historical interest”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

William Kent's ["A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory"](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm) is a good source to know about. Here's how he describes the problems with a partial dependency.

> Consider the following inventory record:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------
    | PART | WAREHOUSE | QUANTITY | WAREHOUSE-ADDRESS |
    ====================-------------------------------
```

> The key here consists of the PART and WAREHOUSE fields together, but WAREHOUSE-ADDRESS is a fact about the WAREHOUSE alone. The basic problems with this design are:
>
> - The warehouse address is repeated in every record that refers to a part stored in that warehouse.
> - If the address of the warehouse changes, every record referring to a part stored in that warehouse must be updated.
> - Because of the redundancy, the data might become inconsistent, with different records showing different addresses for the same warehouse.
> - If at some point in time there are no parts stored in the warehouse, there may be no record in which to keep the warehouse's address.

By the way, you said, "any non-prime attribute should not be dependent on subset of primary key"; you *should* have said something more like "any non-prime attribute should not be dependent on a subset of **any candidate key**". Most articles and books about relational theory simplify their explanations by assuming there's only one candidate key. But the normal forms are defined in terms of *every* candidate key.

Comment: Went through the link. But one more doubt,  why do we need 2NF though ? Cause they could have said in 3NF itself, that all FDs of  type (key field) -> (non-key field) and  (non-key field) -> (non-key field) violates normal form. i.e. why would somebody will go for 2NF instead of  3NF ?

Comment: @omjego: *"Cause they could have said in 3NF itself, that all FDs of type..."* They did say that, more or less. The common definition of 3NF is that a) the relation is in 2NF, and b) there are no transitive dependencies.

Comment: So why would somebody go for 2NF instead of 3NF. i.e. are there any advantages of keeping our schema only in 2NF rather than further normalizing it into 3NF ?

Comment: @omjego, 3NF will add more table joins when querying data, so the main benefit of staying in 2NF is a performance gain.  It comes down to the business needs of the system to dictate if this is desired.  One such case would be if the tables being queried are merely for reporting and are not transactional, then denormalization can be very common.

Comment: @DavidSpenard I understand how 2NF is defined, namely, nonprime shouldn't depend on subset of candidate key. My question, however, is why is dependence on non prime attribute condoned? I mean, both contribute equally in operation anomalies, isn't it?